# Skip errors from any activity in Azure Data Factory and not show in the Monitor

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to do like a if/else using the green arrow or the red arrow of the activity. There is a notebook activity returning an error and I am trying to redirect the red arrow of this activity to another activity, a set variable activity. This set variable activity can return anything and after that, the green arrow of the set variable activity goes to another activity.

It is working with *@activity('Notebook activity').output.pipelineRunId* (set variable activity dynamic content). But it shows like a failure in the Monitor of Azure Data Factory. I want the Monitor to return a success because the last activity is a success (return success in the Monitor if there is only this error in the middle of the pipeline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per description you provided you want to get the pipeline status should be successful irrespective of initial or middle activity response.

**let me first explain you how pipeline status we get as succeed or failed:**

- The dependencies associated with a failed activity determine whether a pipeline succeeds or fails. The simplest explanation is "***If there is a success path, and that path is not taken, then the pipeline status is failure.****"
- The pipeline fails if an action fails without any dependent activities being performed after it. (In other words, if a pipeline's final step fails, the entire thing fails.)
- The pipeline fails if an activity fails and is only followed by another activity that is related to it by a green on-success path.
- The pipeline is successful if only another activity connected by a red on-failure channel follows a failing activity.
- The pipeline is successful if only another activity connected by a blue on-completion path follows a failing activity.

**For your scenario:**

- You need to use on completion path to weather previous activity fails or succeed it will run next activity.
  [image]
- You need to declare both path for an single activity red arrow(on failure) and green arrow(on succeed) so it will not stop in middle because if failure.
  [image]